# Let $M,N$ be subspaces of $V$, and $x,y$ vectors in $V$. then $x+M \subset y+N \iff M \subset N$ and $x-y \in N$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M,N$ be subspaces of a vector space $V, x,y$ vectors in V. Then I am trying to show that $x+M \subset y+N \iff M \subset N$ and $x-y \in N$ .

Suppose $x+M \subset y+N$, then take any $x'=x+m \in x+M$ for $x \in V, m \in M$, then $x' = y+n$ for some  $ y \in V $, $n \in N$. Not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In particular $x+0 \in y+N \implies x = y + n \implies x-y = n \in N$. For the first part, take any $m \in M$, then $m = (x+m) - (x-y) - y= y+ n' - (x-y) - y = n'-(x-y) \in N \implies M \subset N$

Comment: what is n' supposed to mean?

Comment: $n' \in N$ because $x+m \in x+ M \subset y+N  \implies x+m = y+n'$ for some $n' \in N$.